# Bootstrap columns not working but using float it works

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap v4.1.2.I am trying to use `col-md-6` but on my pc `>1300px width` but it is not showing in two columns.But if i am using `float:left` it works
But otherwise it is showing in only one columns and blank another column (both in case of using `container` or `container-fluid` or nothing)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-6">
          .....
       </div>
       <div class="col-6">
          .....
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sure you imported the BS4 css file ? are styles added to the `container` or to the `row` ? in the code Snippet they stay one/row because `md` is for medium screens `≥768px` . THe snippet is below that

Comment: It seems to work just fine when I run the snippet even with version 4 or 4.1.2

Comment: which browser are you using @Tick Twitch

Comment: @ToanLu Chrome Latest version

Answer (score 0):

Basing on Bootstrap 4 Documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) it should look like this :

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   1 of 2
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   2 of 2
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it covers whole width

Comment: what's the difference between this and the question ? except that you changed the behavior of the layout by removing the `md` class ?

Comment: Please be awared that `col-md-*` is still wroking in Bootstrap 4. They only removed `col-xs-*`

Comment: Mine is based on Bootstrap 4 Docs - in question on Bootstrap 3 Docs.
@ToanLu - Thank You for sharing knowledge, friend :)

Comment: In question is Bootstrap 4.1.2, I'm a little incorrect here as they only removed it in Boostrap >4.1 
Bootstrap 4 still has the `col-xs-*`. Sorry about that.
OP said he used 4.1.2 but he imported 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The correct `<link>` to use Bootstrap 4.1.2 CSS is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Have you checked the browser console? Because you're not correctly linking it, the CSS could be getting blocked.

Comment: I have downloaded and checked on  console is checked

Comment: So are you using the `<link>` exactly as I suggested now?

Comment: Yes `<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap.css-css'  href='http://smashing....com/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-6">
          .....
       </div>
       <div class="col-6">
          .....
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```